# Is Display Suite compatible with Panels?

Tags: panels, display-suite

-Drupal 7.37 & Omega4-Subtheme

-Windows7 HP & Toshiba Laptop

-Acquia-DevDesktop WAMP-Stack

1. Just a Simple question.  Is [DS] Display-Suite-Module compatible with [panels] and [panelizer]?
2. By that I mean do they implement conflicting Drupal-Code strategies for accomplishing the same objective.  Do they have any name-space-collisions?
3. I am well aware that they "purpose-wise" cover basically the same territory.
4. I would like to try using one on certain website-projects and the other on other website-projects. I might then leave one unenabled.  When I am familiar with both, I might attempt to use both on the same project.
5. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are compatible in the sense that you can use Panel layouts on DS. *(See picture below)*

You can use DS for one content type and Panels for another content type. Not sure who would win if I enabled both for the same content type, but why would anyone do that?

Where it's *not* compatible is with mini panels, unfortunately you can't insert mini panels into a custom DS dynamic field.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, just want to know if these two were a mess when used together.